# Cannot send CORS requests in h5 game on Telegram Mac?

Tags: telegram

My CORS request not working on Telegram Mac gaming platform, is this expected? If not, how can i solve it.

I deployed a h5 game to vercel, and integrated it to Telegram gaming platform.
I put two requests into the game, one is same origin(call it R1) and the other one is cross origin(call it R2).
On Telegram Mac, R1 works well, but R2 no response or errors as i see.
On Telegram mobile, both R1 and R2 work well.